# How to get min date from Laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, date, min, php-carbon

I have collection `promotions` and each promotion has many `exceptions`:

```
foreach ($promotions as $p) {
    $t = $p->exceptions()
            ->where('sunday','on')
            ->whereDate('start','<=', $c_date)
            ->whereDate('end','>=', $c_date)
            ->get()
            ->sortBy('promotion_id');

    echo $t->min('start'). ' from: '.$t->min('start_time') .' ';
    echo $t->max('end') . ' to: '.$t->max('end_time').'</br>';
}
```

Because a promotion has many exceptions I need to know for each promotion min date and max date.

The code above works good but its uses 'start' as the string not as date and results are not valid.

How I can get min date and max date from the collection.

Comment: What datatype is `start` and `end` stored as?

Comment: get your start date and end date column from the db and user this to parse it.
date('D M, Y', strtotime())

Comment: Are you defining your dates as dates? Check [date mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, it would be wise to have one DATETIME field for each start & end, not separating the date and the time (which could lead you to error). But if you really want a separation:

- Make sure `start` & `end` are stored as **date** in DB, then specify attributes like  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857479/laravel-how-to-set-date-format-on-model-atribute-casting)
- If not, make sure the format of `start` & `end` into "YYYY-MM-DD" when storing values

Comment: Yes start and end are stored as date