# How to Change Date Format From Database In Controller Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I tried to display data in the database, the date format in the database is like 2020-10-11T17: 22: 29.000000Z ", how can i change it just to 2020-10-11, or 11 December 2020 ?

This is my controller

```
 public function get_all_artikel(){
        $data = ArtikelKonten::select(
                'artikel_kategori.nama as kategori','artikel_konten.*')
                ->join('artikel_kategori','artikel_kategori.id','artikel_konten.id_kategori')
                ->get();
        if ($data){
         return response()->json([
                'status' => true,
                'artikel' => $data,
         ],200);}
         else{
             return response()->json([
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'No Artikel were found'
         ],404);}
        }
```

This is my model

```
class ArtikelKonten extends Model
{
    
    protected $table = 'artikel_konten';
    protected $fillable = ['id_kategori', 'gambar', 'tag_program', 'nm_program', 'judul', 'preview', 'konten'];
    
    const CREATED_AT = 'created';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'modified';
}
```

And this is the result

```
{
    "status": true,
    "artikel": [
        {
            "kategori": "Program",
            "id": 4,
            "id_kategori": "2",
            "tag_program": "2",
            "nm_program": "Zakat Mall",
            "gambar": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/photos/1/article1.png",
            "judul": "Mengenalkan Zakat Kepada Anak",
            "preview": null,
            "konten": null,
            "created": "2020-12-10T07:24:50.000000Z",
            "modified": "2020-12-10T08:06:07.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "kategori": "Berita",
            "id": 10,
            "id_kategori": "1",
            "tag_program": "4",
            "nm_program": "Jumat Barokah",
            "gambar": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/photos/1/article2.png",
            "judul": "Suplemen Iman Ditengah Pandemi",
            "preview": null,
            "konten": null,
            "created": "2020-12-11T20:44:25.000000Z",
            "modified": "2020-12-11T20:44:25.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "kategori": "Program",
            "id": 11,
            "id_kategori": "2",
            "tag_program": "2",
            "nm_program": "Zakat Mall",
            "gambar": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/photos/1/article3.png",
            "judul": "Menumbuhkan Semangat Berzakat Umat",
            "preview": null,
            "konten": null,
            "created": "2020-12-11T20:46:23.000000Z",
            "modified": "2020-12-11T20:46:23.000000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

I just wana change the "created": "2020-12-11T20:46:23.000000Z", to "create":"2020-12-11", thanks for your answer guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Laravel 7** uses a new date serialization format when using the **toArray** or **toJson** method on Eloquent models.

If you would like to keep using the previous behavior you can override the `serializeDate()` method on your model :

```
use DateTimeInterface;

protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

See the official upgrade doc  [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#date-serialization) *[7.x]*

Answer (score 0):

use `date()` for clear date and time formate

```
date('d-m-Y', strtotime($value->created));
```

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent Model has a property called `cast` to cast the output of the query to the desired format, in your case just cast your date columns like in [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting):

```
class ArtikelKonten extends Model
{

protected $casts = [
    'created' => 'datetime:Y-m-d','modified' => 'datetime:Y-m-d'
];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel allows to specify the format in which datetime fields should be converted when serialized to array or json

Define $casts property on the model

```php
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
    'updated_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
];
```

Read more : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting

Answer (score 0):

> First way

Just add to the model:

```
  protected function asDateTime($value)
{
    return parent::asDateTime($value)->format('d/m/y');
}
```

> Second way

You can individually customize the format of Eloquent date and datetime casting:

```
protected $casts = [
'created_at'  => 'date:Y-m-d',
'updated_at' =>  'datetime:Y-m-d H:00',];
```

> A few links that helped me to answer
> [link one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857479/laravel-how-to-set-date-format-on-model-attribute-casting)

> A few links that helped me to answer [link two](https://hdtuto.com/article/php-laravel-change-date-format-example)

Answer (score 0):

you cab use accessor for create_at and put this code in your model:

```
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP Laravel Framework

| Laravel Framework | : | 8.42.1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Date tested | : | 22 May 2021 |
| PHP version | : | 7.3.8 |
| Database | : | MariaDB 10.5.8 |
| OS | : | MacOS 10.13.6 High Sierra |

## Question

How to ***transform or change a table column's value/result on the fly*** e.g. format the timestamp into a date (y-m-d h:i:s) format?

## Answer

Using ***Laravel Eloquent: Mutators & Casting*** helps the user to transform data values on the fly by defining them in the Model property.

### Introduction

***Accessors, mutators, and attribute casting*** allow you to transform Eloquent attribute values when you retrieve or set them on model instances. For example, you may want to use the Laravel encrypter to encrypt a value while it is stored in the database, and then automatically decrypt the attribute when you access it on an Eloquent model. Or, you may want to convert a JSON string that is stored in your database to an array when it is accessed via your Eloquent model.

### Attribute Casting

***Attribute casting*** provides functionality similar to accessors and mutators without requiring you to define any additional methods on your model. Instead, your model's $casts property provides a convenient method of converting attributes to common data types.

#### My table scema

[image]

#### My table data

[image]

#### My front result (before cast)

[image]

#### My front result (post cast)

[image]

#### My model file

```php
<?php
// app/Models/Post.php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'description'
    ];

    // I've added this because I want to convert timestamp to 'y-m-d' on the fly
    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
        'updated_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d'
    ];
}
```

#### My controller (I've created controller inside a sub folder 'API')

```php
<?php
// app/Http/Controllers/API/PostController.php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Models\Post;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Validator;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    // all posts, I'm calling this be the default
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all()->toArray();
        return array_reverse($posts);
    }
}
```

#### My routes

```php
<?php
// routes/api.php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\PostController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::get('posts', [PostController::class, 'index']);
Route::group(['prefix' => 'post'], function () {
    Route::post('add', [PostController::class, 'add']);
    Route::get('edit/{id}', [PostController::class, 'edit']);
    Route::post('update/{id}', [PostController::class, 'update']);
    Route::delete('delete/{id}', [PostController::class, 'delete']);
});
```

#### My view (Vue)

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h3 class="text-center">All Posts</h3><br/>
 
        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Created At</th>
                <th>Updated At</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
                <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
                <td style="width: 30%">{{ post.description }}</td>
                <td>{{ post.created_at }}</td>
                <td>{{ post.updated_at }}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <router-link :to="{name: 'edit', params: { id: post.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit
                        </router-link>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="deletePost(post.id)">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
 
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                posts: []
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.axios
                .get('/api/posts')
                .then(response => {
                    this.posts = response.data;
                });
        },
        methods: {
            deletePost(id) {
                this.axios
                    .delete(`/api/post/delete/${id}`)
                    .then(response => {
                        let i = this.posts.map(item => item.id).indexOf(id); // find index of your object
                        this.posts.splice(i, 1)
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```