# Clean an array in Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel

I have a function that retrieves an array of values from a DB with a query in Laravel. I need to clean that array

From this:
2022-02-21 07:40:16

To this:
07:40:16

How can I do?

The function is this:

```php
public function singleDev(Device $deviceID)
{
    $data = DataFromRasp::where('MAC', 'C4:A5:DF:24:05:7E')->get()->pluck('RSSI', 'created_at')->toArray();
    $time_array = [];
    $rssi_array = [];
    $cnt = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        array_push($time_array, $key);
        array_push($rssi_array, $value);
        if ($value < -60) {
            $cnt++;
            if ($cnt >= 2) {
   
            }
        }
    }
    dd($time_array);
    
    return view('backend.auth.user.singleDevice', compact("time_array", "rssi_array"));
}
```

Comment: do you want to show the time only instead of full datetime?

Comment: Exactly, I need only time

Comment: then why are you doing on the backend i.e controller side just use format function of carbon on blade template file.

Comment: Because I need it to add them in a chart

Comment: check my solution .

Comment: Can you cast the field to a carbon object with a specific format in the model?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50535218/2708787

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public function singleDev(Device $deviceID){
        $data = DataFromRasp::select('RSSI', 'created_at')->where('MAC', 'C4:A5:DF:24:05:7E')->get();
        $time_array = [];
        $rssi_array = [];
        $cnt = 0;
        foreach($data as $dataItem){
            array_push($time_array, $dataItem->created_at->format('H:i:s'));
            array_push($rssi_array, $dataItem->RSSI);
            if($value < -60){
                $cnt++;
                if($cnt >=2){

                }
            }
        }
        dd($time_array);

        return view('backend.auth.user.singleDevice', compact("time_array", "rssi_array"));
    }
```

Comment: I made a mistake. `$dataItem->created_at->format('H:i:s')` instead of `$dataItem->format('H:i:s')`. Edited.

Comment: It gives me this error: Call to a member function format() on int

Comment: Now I have the error: Trying to get property 'created_at' of non-object

Comment: Please, show code of `$data` getting

Comment: This is the data that I retrive from the DB:
https://imgur.com/a/GgvY18d

Comment: Remove `pluck` method from your code. The method is unnecessary. Copy whole of my code, include `$data = DataFromRasp::select('RSSI', 'created_at')->where('MAC', 'C4:A5:DF:24:05:7E')->get();` line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the power of Laravel Collection methods like map, pluck, and make the solution short.

```
$data = DataFromRasp::select('RSSI', 'created_at')->where('MAC', 'C4:A5:DF:24:05:7E')->map(function($d) {
    $d->timeValue = $d->created_at->format('H:i:s');
    return $d;
});

$time_array = $data->pluck('timeValue')->toArray();
$rssi_array = $data->pluck('RSSI')->toArray();
```

Comment: It doesn't work...Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::map()

Comment: remove the `get` method. check my updated answer.

Comment: I don't use get method

Comment: I was explaining my answer. Just use the latest solution.