# I changed laravel collection to Array by toArray() function, My date format is changed

Tags: laravel-8

I created a collection then it changed it to Array by toArray() function. In the collection, my date is 2022-08-24 but after converting it into an array it returns 2022-08-23T00:00:00.000000Z value.
Does anyone have any solution or reason behind this change?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: how to set date format on model attribute casting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37857479/laravel-how-to-set-date-format-on-model-attribute-casting)

Comment: This is done (customized) using [Attribute Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Date Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting)

> By default, Eloquent will cast the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns
> to instances of [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon), which extends the PHP DateTime class and
> provides an assortment of helpful methods. You may cast additional
> date attributes by defining additional date casts within your model's
> $`casts` property array. Typically, dates should be cast using the
> `datetime` or `immutable_datetime` cast types.
>
> When defining a `date` or `datetime` cast, you may also specify the date's
> format. This format will be used when the [model is serialized to an
> array or JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-serialization):

*In your model:*

```php
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
    ];
```